# libodbc.2.dylib not found. Trying to connect to an SQL Server database with an ODBC connection on C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, sql-server, unity-game-engine, odbc

I am trying to access a SQL database within my Unity project through an ODBC connection. The code compiles correctly, but, when I run the scene in Unity, I get a `DLLNotFoundException` for the file `libodbc.2.dylib`. This error occurs when I open the connection using `connection.Open()`.

I am using Windows OS and my project settings are all tailored for Windows. After researching `libodbc.2.dylib`, it seems like DLL is made for MacOS. I have installed both Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 and 17 for SQL Server. The database is accessible from SSMS.

Here is my code:

```
var queryString = "SELECT firstName FROM Students";

var connectionString =

    "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:********.database.windows.net,1433;" +
        "Database=********;Uid=********;Pwd={********}Encrypt=yes;" +
        "TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;";

var command = new OdbcCommand(queryString);

using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    command.Connection = connection;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Note: sensitive information is replaced with **********.

Comment: Is the exception you mention the one you get when using MS ODBC Driver 13 & 17?

Comment: Yes. I have tried both version independently and the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot practically use ODBC inside Unity [due to limitations in Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/odbc/). Use a managed (i.e., pure C#) SQL driver instead, [like this one.](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient)